# How to validate struct properties in swift

Tags: swift, validation, struct, properties

I have a struct,

```
struct State { 
  let email: String
  let phoneNumber: String
}
```

I pass this values from the previous class like

```
 class.State(email: "email", phoneNumber: "021000000")
```

Now, I assign these to textfields and validation is done in `shouldChangeCharactersIn`, if user edit it.

I want to do  validation inside struct for email, and phoneNumber
and return the result using closure. (Because this updated struct is being passed to other class to enable my button only if properties are valid).

I am not able to call validation method inside my struct.

How to validate the struct properties or access class methods inside struct ?  Am I going to the right direction, I am confused ?

Comment: You mention an "updated" struct, but both fields are declared immutable, so do you mean a new `State` instance as the updated one? If both fields are immutable, you can simply make a throwing/failable initializer and validate them in the initializer of `State`. If they should be mutable, you can simply validate them in property observers/create custom setters for them.

Comment: Yes. you are absolutely right. As a new State instance. Any examples would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

## Approach:

1. Keep track of the field / indbexpath being edited
2. When the characters change, do the following:

   - Update the relevant field in your model
   - Do your validation
   - Based on the outcome of your validation, do some action, example enable / disable Done button

## Code:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    let existingText = textField.text as NSString?
    
    let changedText = existingText?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    
    update(withChangedText: changedText) //Update model and do your validation, example enable / disable Done button 
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: My fields inside struct is immutable. I am able to create only a new instance or copy of it with updated value. So I cannot update the struct in shouldChangeCharactersIn

Comment: IMHO `struct` is a value type meaning it is a value, not sure you would want to have your model as a `struct`. "5", "abcd" these are values. Now a model could contain values that is fine but a model would need **identity**. I would leave it to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Since both fields of your struct are immutable, you can simply do the validation in the initializer of the struct. You should create a failable initializer, which fails in case the validation fails.

```
struct State {
    let email: String
    let phoneNumber: String

    init?(email:String,phoneNumber:String) {
        //Do your own validation here
        if (email.contains("@") && phoneNumber.count == 9){
            self.email = email
            self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

State(email: "a@b.com", phoneNumber: "123456789") // creates a State instance
State(email: "ab.com", phoneNumber: "123") //nil
```

You can validate your user input in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` by supplying the user input as the input parameters to the initializer for `State` and checking whether the return value is `nil` or not.